# Reflection of light on a moving mirror - Lorentz transformations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, optics

> Setting: Let's consider a moving mirror at constant speed in z-direction. A light ray of frequency $\omega$ falls onto the mirror. Its wave vector $k$ forms an angle $\theta$ with the vector normal to the mirror.

I would now like to find the angle of reflection with respect to the vector $\vec{e}_z$ normal to the mirror by using the wave four-vector $k^{\mu}=(\omega/c,\vec{k})$. First I wanted to transform the four-vector to a system $K'$ where the mirror is at rest. I know that the transformed position-vector can be written as $$\begin{Bmatrix}x^{{0}^{'}}=\gamma(x^0-\beta x_\parallel)\\x_\parallel'=\gamma(x_\parallel-\beta x^0)\\x_\perp'=x_\perp \end{Bmatrix}$$ The k-vector in the K-system looks like this $$\begin{Bmatrix}k^0=\omega/c=k\\k_\parallel=k_z=k*cos(\theta)\\k_\perp = k_y=k*sin(\theta)\end{Bmatrix}$$
My problem is now how to transform the k vector into the primed system K'. 
It should look like this: $$\begin{Bmatrix}k'^0=k \gamma(1-\beta *cos(\theta))\\k'_\parallel=k \gamma(cos\theta -\beta)\\k_\perp'=k_\perp = k*sin(\theta)\end{Bmatrix}$$
The main question is: How do the different cosines come to be?
**Note:** I know that a similar, but broader question already has been asked here with the title "law of reflection for a moving mirror". But the given references do not provide any insight into this specific problem.

Comment: Hint: how do you transform four-vectors from one frame to another?

Comment: I have to apply a Lorentz transformation by multiplying the 4 Vector with a transformation matrix $\Lambda$.

Comment: And if you have the transform from $(x^0, x_{||})$ to $(x^{0'}, x'_{||})$, what is the transformation matrix?

Comment: I think it should be something like $$\Lambda =\begin{Bmatrix}\gamma && \gamma \vec{v}^T/c \\ \gamma \vec{v}/c && 1+ \gamma^2 \vec{v} \vec{v}^T/c^2(1+\gamma)\end{Bmatrix} $$

Comment: You are complicating yourself way too much. Just look at the first set of equations in your question: It takes position four-vector $x$ into position four vector $x'$.  What is this transformation in matrix form?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to write $$\Lambda = \begin{Bmatrix}\gamma && -\gamma \beta && 0 && 0 \\-\gamma \beta && \gamma && 0 && 0 \\ 0 &&0&&1&&0 \\ 0&&0&&0&&1 \end{Bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ups, that's actually pretty simple: I just have to apply the same transformations as in the first part. I don't know why I haven't seen that before... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Happens. Welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the same transformations as given for the position vector x. They show the "standard" Lorentz-transformation. 
Then apply these to: \begin{Bmatrix}k^0=\omega/c=k\\k_\parallel=k_z=k*cos(\theta)\\k_\perp = k_y=k*sin(\theta)\end{Bmatrix}
This gives \begin{Bmatrix}k^{{0}^{'}}=\gamma(k^0-\beta k_\parallel)\\k_\parallel'=\gamma(k_\parallel-\beta k^0)\\k_\perp'=k_\perp \end{Bmatrix}
Using the relations given for k in the K-system we get the desired result.